# Performance of single-writer, different reader vs same thread

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

I have an ‘order-manager’ application and I follow ‘single writer’ approach for processing order events to avoid any race conditions.

So I have a single main thread which is busy spinning for incoming order events and processes the events without making any blocking calls.

This main thread also requires static data for validating order events etc. So I store the static data in an in-memory cache (java map).

I wanted to understand the most performant way of accessing the in-memory static data by my main thread.

A) Should the main thread itself be responsible for maintaining the in-memory static data so that there is just one thread for everything and hence achieving max CPU throughput avoiding any thread related contention/locks.

Or

B) Should I store the static data in a ConcurrentHashmap using a separate dedicated thread and share this map with my main thread (single writer, different reader thread). I read somewhere that as long as there is a single writer thread, the reader threads’ access is optimised across CPU cores using special channels. But again, with this second approach, I still have to use a ConcurrentHashMap which will bring in latency associated with threads and locks.

I wanted to hear a view on what’s the best approach for attaining max throughput.

Comment: Have you checked [`ReadWriteLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html)? Max throughput is achieved without synchronization but at the cost of potentially outdated data. Then it's all about when it's accessed by which thread...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as a classical event stream processing. One thread is simpler and usually higher performance (inter-thread communication always has some cost). Doing a job in a separate thread gives benefits if there is a CPU-intensive task which could run concurrently, which is not usually a case in order-stream processing.

Also check ideas of LMAX Disruptor or Real Logic Aeron.

Comment: Thanks Kan. In fact I am using LMAX Disruptor for the order event processing (single business consumer thread reading off from the ring buffer). As you rightly said, the static data cache related updates are not CPU intensive and not frequent and that’s why I am not keen on using a separate thread for maintaining that data. So one of the options is that I send the static data updates also to the ring buffer and let my main thread store them in a map hence avoiding any inter-thread communication during order event’s processing.

Comment: @saurabh.in Sending updates to another ring buffer is also kind of inter-thread communication and also is not free (e.g. the buffer itself is a memory and atomic offsets). However, it's hard to tell how the cost is differ from the data manipulation cost - it's very specific to your app. So, the only way to do it right - do experiments. Measure perf, try a change, measure perf again and choose what's better.

Comment: actually I meant sending the static data event to the same ring buffer which is used for order events. That way my single main thread will get order as well as static data events and will process them differently (for static data it will simply store them in a hashmap). And so, everything will be handled by one single thread. The static data updates will be very few say 10 / day so my main thread will 99% of the time be serving order events. Also, AFAIK the ring buffer doesn’t involve locking but surely I will read up about atomic offsets which you mentioned.

Comment: @saurabh.in I would vote for this approach of sending static data evens to the same buffer and maintaining simple Hash Map. If you do a shared concurrent map - it's not easy do fast. E.g. ConcurrentHashMap uses locks, so you should avoid using such data structure in the event stream. The atomics are usually faster, but still they force memory reads, etc, while single-threaded access may use CPU caches more actively.

Comment: there is a related question I have asked separately around the use of hazelcast in this application. It would be great to see if you have any comments to this too - https://stackoverflow.com/q/59579079/3049693

Answer (score 0):

There is more than two way to share state between threads. And it is almost impossible to say what one is more suitable for your case. The right way is to benchmark several solutions (jmh, jcstrees).

It is considered that a single-thread is the best solution if it can provide enough performance due to simplicity, maintenance cost, etc.
But multi-threading is a necessary evil if we are trying to get max throughput in general case.

If calculating/maintenance the static data is too expensive, I would choose the second approach with one addition. I would consider using the solution with publication immutable map thou volatile variable instead of CHM.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on nature of static data in cache. If that data doesn't change while your application works than you can create and populate that cache in a main thread and use it in the same main thread.
But if that cache need to be updated (periodically or as a response to some events) then it is better to have a separate thread creating cache, populating it initially and then do updates, because if you start doing cache updates in the main thread then that main thread will not be able to handle orders until cache update is finished.

Comment: the cache is static and doesn’t change often - maybe 10 times in a day. So I was thinking of letting the main thread maintain it in a map when it gets static data related updates. The small processing needed to extract the static data from an incoming event from an external system could be handled by a separate thread which can then drop the data which is ready to store into a ring buffer (lmax disruptor) which my main thread could read and store in a hashmap.