# Using Hazelcast map with LMAX disruptor - performance impact

Tags: java, performance, disruptor-pattern

We have a requirement to run Active-Active instances of an order manager application for elasticity. Within our team, Hazelcast is the preferred distributed cache for sharing state across elastic instances.

Within the application I am using single-writer pattern along with LMAX disruptor lib. So basically I have a single busy spinning main thread which reads incoming order events from the disruptor (ring buffer) and quickly processes it without involving any blocking operation.

Now the only issue is that, as soon as my main thread receives an event, it first performs a lookup in a Hazelcast distributed map (to fetch current order’s state), and hazelcast lookup is relatively a slow operation (~5-10 millis). I wanted to understand:

1) if this is still an acceptable thing I.e. reading from a distributed map when using LMAX disruptor

2) plus since Hazelcast calls are thread safe involving distributed locks and LMAX guys suggest avoiding thread related locks in the main business thread so that CPU optimized code caches remain hot, does making a call to hazelcast an anti-pattern from LMAX Disruptor’s main processing thread?

Could someone add their 2 cents on this?

Comment: Hi @saurabh.in were you able to implement disruptor on a hazelcast distributed map ?

Comment: Hi @user3203030, yes. Indeed. However I could bring the event processing only to as fast at 2-3 millis per txn. As was guessed in my question above, Hazelcast is the blocker now (DB was but I stop storing in DB when that becomes a bottleneck). We can fully get rid of Hazelcast cluster with Kafka partitioning. But then we need one component to direct the vendor messages into specific Kafka partitions within the topic, and each of the elastic instance of my component can then connect to the specific partition of the Kafka topic. Kafka partitions also support sticky connection.

Comment: Wow @saurabh.in can you share a sample code snippet of disruptor running on a distributed hazelcast object (like map or queue). Will be of great use

Comment: hi user3203030, to be clear, disruptor and hazelcast cluster had not direct relation. I used hazelcast as a general distributed cache at the entry point of receiving an event - to decide which of the elastic instances should process it (this is a blocking operation and can take from 1 to 5 millis per event!). I used hazelcast distributed lock (tried writing to a hazelcast map from all instances with same event key and whichever instance was able to insert the data was allowed to proceed with the event). LMAX disruptor had nothing to do with the hazelcast cache.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it's not acceptable, of course. IMap is not only blocking for indefinite time, it also doing network calls.

I think a way to go is to

- either split off the IMap access into another thread and communicate
  with it using async events in separate ring buffers
- or subscribe to IMap entry listener and store data in the memory (if it fits).

Comment: thanks. I am considering of moving the call to IMap in a separate thread and wrapping the fetched order along with the incoming event in a single msg and sending it to the ring buffer which my main thread reads from. But the problem is with writes. When the main thread is done processing the event, it has to update the shared state of the order in IMap. So the writes has to be synchronous to ensure that other instances have visibility to the latest state for the order. Otherwise if the next instance happens to process corresponding order’s next event, it can find stale order obj.

Comment: @saurabh.in Not sure if I understand it correctly, but it is curious why do you process same order by multiple instances. It's easier if one instance will process all events for a given order. You could have partitioning for scalability. Is it a requirement or a particular design?

Comment: yes that’s a good point. On one end of the order manger we have kafka broker so I indeed ensure that the same instance gets all events for a certain order id using kafka partitioning. On the other side there is concurrent websocket connectivity using different connection details one per active instance (wasn’t my personal preference). And so on this side, I have no control on which instance gets it. I could maintain the orde id-> instance in an IMap to ensure same instance gets it but that’s adding another state in the system.

Comment: @saurabh.in I still not sure what's your architecture. For active-active you should use some replication and leader selection workflow. Afair Kafka does it out-of-box. Not sure how does Hazelcast involved and why is it even needed at all for order stream and what's its role.

Comment: the order manager application is connected to an internal system on one end via kafka so we get the benefits of msg routing etc. But the other end connects to vendor server using websocket connections - one connection per active instance. Any event originating from vendor is copied to all active instances. And so i use hazelcast to decide which instance could process the event. Also, the order context (post event processing) is stored in hazelcast so that it could be fetched by any of the instances. But I see your point of avoiding hazelcast for storing order ctx.

Comment: as per my above comment, I can keep order obj local to instances(instead of IMap) with session stickiness, but recovering the instances from DB, when starting them from cold would be a pain specially when the number of instances are dynamic. It will be difficult to decide which obj belongs to which instance, say when we descaled from 3 instances to 2 instances.

Comment: There is no magic anywhere. Kafka solves the problem by partitioning. When scaling happens it does partition reassignment, blocking all consumers. Hz also does something similar.

Comment: If you need performance, then it's bad idea to scale on the fly as it would cause latency spikes.

Comment: thanks. We won’t scale on the fly but my point was that say if we had 3 active instances, and one goes down and never comes back up, then that instance’s local orders’ state needs to be distributed amongst the other 2 instances - this when I go with the approach of keeping orders local to specific instances(sticky connection). And hence I m storing all orders in hazelcast instead, which is shared across all active instances. I think the ideal solution for my use case is Active-Passive model for best performance. And I have seen this in my previous places where low latency was important.

Comment: @saurabh.in You are assuming that if you _storing all orders in hazelcast instead_ then magic happens and it just works. No, hz also implements some kind of approach to distribute amont instances, and It works by a price of slowness and unpredictable latency.

Comment: Sure @kan. I get that. My point is recovery from dB to hz is easy compared to copying specific set of order objecrs to specific instances. Anyway, most of my points are answered/discussed.. so thanks a lot for your inputs :).

Comment: I think if you already use Kafka it could be more effective to use its topics for recovery too. It also supports topic compaction and partitioning. Mixing different things is cumbersome and may lead to not trivial rare bugs with concurrency, recovery and consistency between DB, Hz, Kafka and disruptors.